# Application of polynomial function multiplicity

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

What is the application of polynomial function multiplicity
$\space n.\space $ Is there any real problem related to polynomial function with multiplicity roots? Any real application for polynomial function with multiplicity $\space n?\space $

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Applications are broad. Applications I can think of are in engineering associated with civil engineering. Like if you want to find critical points of stress on a building. There is many applications.

Comment: In my particular field, we use Laplace transforms to turn equations of motion (eg. $F=m\frac{d^2x}{dt^2}$) into ratios of polynomials. Turns out, the poles (roots of the denominator) predict most of the behavior of a physical system. Depending on how many moving parts you have, you can theoretically be working with any degree polynomials, although $2\leq n\leq4$ is most common.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you want to find out how "wide" a parabola needs to be for a given depth/heighth. For example if $y=x^2 \implies x^2+0x-y=0.\space $ If such a paraobola (like a dish antenna) is $4'$ deep, then

$x=\dfrac{-0\pm\sqrt{0^2-4(1)(-y)}}{2(1)}=\pm\dfrac{2}{2}=\pm 1.\quad$ This means  you must plan on two feet of horizontal space for the antenna. This answer is too-simple but it shows how multiple solutions $(x=\pm1)$ can be useful.

Without going into detail, another equation $\quad k=\sqrt{m^2-A},\quad  \sqrt{A+1} \le m \le \dfrac{A+1}{2}\quad$ has three $f(m,k)$ soultions if $A=105$ meaning there are $\space 3$ Pythagorean triples

$$f(11,4)=(105,88,137)\quad 
f(13,8)=(105,208,233)\quad 
f(19,16)=(105,608,617)$$
where side-$A=105.\quad$ Multiple solutions are all around us and they do have real world meaning.